# OrCriteria taking forever to execute using Tridion content delivery api

Tags: tridion, tridion-content-delivery

I am converting a SQL query into broker API functionality. The query basically retrieves custom meta data based on key and value filters. The issue is when I am joining two criteria using or criteria the `query.executequery` takes forever and the control never returns. The code that I am using is as below

```
        PublicationCriteria pubCriteria = new PublicationCriteria(80);

        //1st query
        CustomMetaKeyCriteria keyCriteria1 = new CustomMetaKeyCriteria("PublicationType");

        CustomMetaValueCriteria valueCriteria11 = new CustomMetaValueCriteria("Report", Criteria.Like);
        CustomMetaValueCriteria valueCriteria12 = new CustomMetaValueCriteria("Video", Criteria.Like);
        Criteria valueCriteria1 = CriteriaFactory.Or(valueCriteria11, valueCriteria12);
        Criteria criteria1 =CriteriaFactory.And(keyCriteria1, valueCriteria1);

        //2nd query

        CustomMetaKeyCriteria keyCriteria2 = new CustomMetaKeyCriteria("Tags");

        CustomMetaValueCriteria valueCriteria21 = new CustomMetaValueCriteria("tcm:80-20641", Criteria.Equal);
        CustomMetaValueCriteria valueCriteria22 = new CustomMetaValueCriteria("tcm:80-20645", Criteria.Equal);
        Criteria valueCriteria2 = CriteriaFactory.Or(valueCriteria21, valueCriteria22);
        Criteria criteria2 =  CriteriaFactory.And(keyCriteria2, valueCriteria2);


        Criteria querycriteria = CriteriaFactory.Or(criteria1, criteria2);
        Criteria finalCriteria = CriteriaFactory.And(pubCriteria, querycriteria);
        Query query = new Query(criteria2);
        query.SetResultFilter(new LimitFilter(10));
        var n = query.ExecuteQuery();
```

I have tried using new orcriteria and passing the criteria as array but this also didn't work.

Comment: Please use http://tridion.stackexchange.com for Tridion questions.

Comment: sorry, actually a couple of week ago i tried to ask question on tridion.stackexchage.com but was not able to post question but now its allowing me. In future i wil ask question on tridion.stackexchange.

Comment: It was in private beta until earlier this week.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of weeks back I tried the same, it worked for me. I have put my findings here. http://vadalis.com/custom-meta-query-from-tridionbroker-database/

Note : my broker database is very small.